# MonoDevelop build error "The search could not be finished"

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I am currently developing a C# application to be cross compatible in Windows and Ubuntu. I am developing the software in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows and copying the project to ubuntu and make any modifications that are required using MonoDevelop.

This has been working perfectly all the time but now for some reason it isn't.

When I try to do a search and replace across the entire project which has always worked is now coming up with an that says 'The search could not be finished. Could not find file /*myproject/myproject*/Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5.

Also when I run the project it says that it builds successfully but when run it looks as if it is running the previous build instead of the latest build.

Comment: For the last bit, try doing a `clean all` and then `build all`. I've had problems similar to this with MonoDevelop

Comment: Also, perhaps post output of `mdtool build mysolution.sln`. You might consider taking the question to monodevelop IRC

Comment: @Earlz I have tried doing that but same thing. Also I have tried to modify the code in Mono to show a message box when the software is launched and told it to rebuild, it says the build is successful but still seems to run the old version

Comment: Have you tried manually building it, using `xbuild` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have tried uninstall MonoDevelop and reinstalling and reverting the software to a much earlier version which I know previously worked however the same build problem. The only way I can get round it so far I've found is to make the modifications that I need to make in Windows and then copy to Mono and the software works fine. When I modify code in Mono though it will still say that its built but run the previous version without the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I experienced issues with searching for files it was the MonoDevelop parser information files that was out of sync. Try deleting all .pidb files and do a rebuild.