# Tarball creation - referenced file outside the root solution directory

Tags: c#, monodevelop, autotools

I've created a Tarball project within monodevelop (2.6 on Ubuntu 11.10) for a C# solution that's being ported from Windows to mono-land. It's currently set to generate new makefiles for each of the projects in the solution with no switches set.

When I build the tarball project, I end up with a handful of these errors:

File '' not found.

...which look like they cause these errors downstream:

The solution '(blah)' is referencing the file '' which is located outside the root solution directory.

I've tried removing the .pidb files, as recommended in this [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523952/monodevelop-build-problem). But my issue is more or a packaging-time one; building the solution works just fine. Has anyone figured out (1) how to determine which file(s) the project is choking on, and (2) how to include these files in the output?

Answer (score 2):

I could reproduce the same issue with MonoDevelop 2.8.6.3. I got the following errors when trying to export the project or create a tarball:

```
File '(...)/Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5' not found.
File '(...)/Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1' not found.
File '(...)/Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1' not found.
File '' not found.
File '' not found.
The project '(ProjectName)' is referencing the file '' which is located outside the project directory.
The project '(ProjectName)' is referencing the file '' which is located outside the project directory.
```

**Solution:** You need to clean up your `.CSPROJ` files to make them compatible with MonoDevelop.

In my case, I got rid of the `File '' not found` error by removing the following entry:

```
<SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
```

Somehow I had checked the "Sign assembly" checkbox option in the Project Properties window in Visual Studio but didn't provide a path for the key file.

I got rid of the other errors by removing this ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
    <Visible>False</Visible>
    <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
    <Install>false</Install>
  </BootstrapperPackage>
  <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
    <Visible>False</Visible>
    <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
    <Install>true</Install>
  </BootstrapperPackage>
  <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
    <Visible>False</Visible>
    <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
    <Install>true</Install>
  </BootstrapperPackage>
</ItemGroup>
```

Hope that helps other people!

Comment: Thanks for posting this response! I've since moved on from the project, but I reloaded it the other day to see if there were signed assemblies in the solution (there are a bunch of .csproj files that make up the solution). Unfortunately, it wasn't the cause of the blank File '' Not Found errors. But I do think you're on to something -- there are probably some phantom assembly references that are decorated differently under Windows and Mono (?). I'll pass along your suggestion to the current project owners.